Optimizing Custom Double Release Lock and Semaphore in Python asyncio
I am currently working on a project involving file operations that need to be handled by multiple processors concurrently, but not by other threads simultaneously. For this, I've devised a concept called a Double Release Lock and a Double Release Semaphore, implemented using Python's asyncio. The key idea here is that pairs of two processors are somewhat synchronized by means of the lock and semaphore. Hence why they should only unlock or release after two release calls instead of one. This ensures that two processors can read a file at the same time, and it limits the number of processors operating simultaneously.
What I have implemented:

Double Release Lock: This lock is designed to ensure that it only becomes available (unlocked) after two release() calls have been made. This is used when two processors are to read the same file before its modified by the next processors.
Double Release Semaphore: Similar to the lock, this semaphore is meant to manage access with a slightly broader scope. It allows a certain number of tasks to enter, but each task must signal completion twice before it is considered truly complete, effectively doubling the release requirement.

Questions:

Are there better alternatives to achieve the same functionality, perhaps using existing libraries or different synchronization primitives?
Could these mechanisms face any potential issues under high concurrency scenarios?

I am looking for insights or suggestions on how to refine or validate this approach, or if there are alternative strategies that might be more effective or safer in terms of concurrency handling.

Are you saying you want to enforce exactly (or at most) two readers in a shared-read exclusive-write lock? Exactly what semantics do you need?

BTW you seem to be conflating processes and processors, unless I misunderstand you. Processes doing blocking file I/O may switch physical processor fairly frequently even if they do hold a special lock.

In the context of my implementation, I'm dealing with asyncio in Python, which primarily handles concurrency through coroutines, not threads or physical processors. The terminology I initially used ('processors') was incorrect in this context. What I meant was 'concurrent tasks' being managed by asyncio's event loop.  The Double Release Lock and Semaphore mechanisms are intended to ensure that exactly two tasks can complete their work with the shared resource before another set of tasks can proceed.

Such an approach might work - but you'd have to fill in a "minimal reproducible example"  there - (Lock class implementation, and some co-routine actually making use of it) so we could check any errors, or hint in the direction for correct implementation. (if it already works, the question may be pointless)
